# Default value cannot be 'Unset'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I have a attached property when I attach this to a xaml element I am getting an exception called **"Default value cannot be 'Unset'"**

My Attached property logic

```
    public static DataTemplate GetFooterContentTemplate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DataTemplate)obj.GetValue(FooterContentTemplateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFooterContentTemplate(DependencyObject obj, DataTemplate value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FooterContentTemplateProperty, value);
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GetFooterContentTemplate.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterContentTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FooterContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(RadWindowFooterProperties), new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue));


    public static Object GetFooterContent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Object)obj.GetValue(FooterContentProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFooterContent(DependencyObject obj, Object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FooterContentProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RadWindowFooterContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FooterContent", typeof(Object), typeof(RadWindowFooterProperties), new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue));
```

My XAML:

```
     <Grid x:Name="FooterRoot"  Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="42">
                        <Border Background="{StaticResource ShellFooterBrush}"/>
                        <Border Background="{DynamicResource ShellTileBrush}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=(Local:RadWindowFooterProperties.FooterContent),RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=(Local:RadWindowFooterProperties.FooterContentTemplate),RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>

                    </Grid>
```

Please let me know where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is not a valid default value for a dependency property. Unless you want to specify a default value other than `null`, you don't need to register property metadata at all.

You would also have to change the declaration of `FooterContentTemplateProperty` to use `RegisterAttached` instead of `Register`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterContentTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FooterContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(RadWindowFooterProperties));

public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FooterContent", typeof(Object), typeof(RadWindowFooterProperties));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if I read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) correctly it states:

> Setting a DefaultValue of UnsetValue is specifically disallowed.

So I would recommend to set a default value like `null` or anything more appropriate for your usecase.